# Duplicator folder permissions Linux

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, permissions, file-permissions

I am trying to migrate a WordPress site using the Duplicator plugin. I have created an ec2 instance on AWS, installed Apache and copied over the files from the Duplicator backup to `/var/www/html/`.

When I visit the site on the browser going to `myip/dup-installer/main.installer.php` I get the following error: [image: duplicator permission error]

My **www** folder permissions are : `drwxrwxrwx  3 root www-data 4096`.

My **html** folder permissions are: `drwxrwxrwx 7 www-data www-data 4096`.

My **dup-installer** folder permissions are: `drwxrwxrwx  8 www-data www-data  4096`.

And finally, my **main.installer.php** file permissions are: `-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data    20437`.

It all looks correct but I don't understand why I'm getting the error when I visit the installer. Is there something wrong with my permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your permissions are fully open on your www directory. That shouldn't be like that, most files should not be world writable.

you should change this to 755 via this command:
`sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www`

Note, use the correct path to your www directory if it isn't correct for you.

regarding your missing CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) file, this is probably because your copy didn't have the correct priv to copy it. Might look on the original server to see if you can grab it and move it over.

Comment: Ah, thank you for the 755 recomendation. I will do that.
I am not sure I understand the second part of your question though. Are you saying that on the server I'm migrating from, there should be a CSRF file that I never got? Would dropping in that in the webroot solve my issue above?

Comment: Yes, that's what the error is telling you "CSRF File not found" 

Now that could be a permission issue, ie, www-data group couldn't access that file because of incorrect permissions... OR the file is missing

Comment: I see, this makes sense.

I have followed your recommendation from above and now **www**, **html** and **dup-installer**  are ```drwxr-xr-x```. The **main.installer.php** is now ```-rwxr-xr-x```.

Does this look better?

I shall ask for the missing CSRF file and see if that helps. Would it have .csrf extension? How would they recognise what to send me?

Comment: Yep, that's much better...

Maybe good enough for an accepted answer?

Comment: Oh yes, I will definitely accept your answer. Thank you very much for your time!!!

I just have one more question on how would the owners of the original server recognise the CSRF file? Would it have a .csrf extension or something that stands out? Sorry, I'm completely new to this.

Comment: Also, all of the files I have uploaded come from what the Wordpress Duplicator plugin gets in the backup folder. Is there a way to check if the file is there and it can't be accessed because of incorrect permissions as you mentioned in your first scenario?

Comment: That last one was a bit of a leap to answer, had to trace some code... BUT your filename should be with 'dup-installer-csrf__[ package hash ].txt'
see here:
https://github.com/Stafflancer/Mozaik/blob/c7e689fd158a7942824892a3888ee940de0ab7d3/wp-content/plugins/duplicator/installer/dup-installer/classes/class.csrf.php#L163

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I had to execute `[website-hush-information]_installer-backup.php` which sits one level before the `dup-installer` folder.

I was trying to execute the `main.installer.php` inside `dup-installer` based on previous experience with this plugin, but in this version, this was not needed.

Thanks for the help @JP-LISN, it pointed me in to the correct direction by the process of elimination.